# How correctly pass parameters in controllers?

Tags: java, scala, playframework

I am new in `Play Framework` and need some advice.

In my project I send `AJAX` request but unfortunatly Play Framework raise error which you can see below. From error message you can notice that problem most likely in controller. Where was my mistake? How to fix this error?

```
[error] application - 

! @79mg8k016 - Internal server error, for (GET) [/] ->

play.api.UnexpectedException: Unexpected exception[CreationException: Unable to create injector, see the following errors:

1) No implementation for play.api.db.Database was bound.
  while locating play.api.db.Database
    for the 1st parameter of controllers.GetValuesController.<init>(GetValuesController.scala:14)
  while locating controllers.GetValuesController
    for the 4th parameter of router.Routes.<init>(Routes.scala:33)
  at play.api.inject.RoutesProvider$.bindingsFromConfiguration(BuiltinModule.scala:121):
Binding(class router.Routes to self) (via modules: com.google.inject.util.Modules$OverrideModule -> play.api.inject.guice.GuiceableModuleConversions$$anon$1)

1 error]
    at play.core.server.DevServerStart$$anon$1.reload(DevServerStart.scala:186)
    at play.core.server.DevServerStart$$anon$1.get(DevServerStart.scala:124)
    at play.core.server.AkkaHttpServer.handleRequest(AkkaHttpServer.scala:241)
    at play.core.server.AkkaHttpServer.$anonfun$createServerBinding$1(AkkaHttpServer.scala:138)
    at akka.stream.impl.fusing.MapAsyncUnordered$$anon$26.onPush(Ops.scala:1304)
    at akka.stream.impl.fusing.GraphInterpreter.processPush(GraphInterpreter.scala:519)
    at akka.stream.impl.fusing.GraphInterpreter.processEvent(GraphInterpreter.scala:482)
    at akka.stream.impl.fusing.GraphInterpreter.execute(GraphInterpreter.scala:378)
    at akka.stream.impl.fusing.GraphInterpreterShell.runBatch(ActorGraphInterpreter.scala:588)
    at akka.stream.impl.fusing.GraphInterpreterShell$AsyncInput.execute(ActorGraphInterpreter.scala:472)
Caused by: com.google.inject.CreationException: Unable to create injector, see the following errors:

1) No implementation for play.api.db.Database was bound.
  while locating play.api.db.Database
    for the 1st parameter of controllers.GetValuesController.<init>(GetValuesController.scala:14)
  while locating controllers.GetValuesController
    for the 4th parameter of router.Routes.<init>(Routes.scala:33)
  at play.api.inject.RoutesProvider$.bindingsFromConfiguration(BuiltinModule.scala:121):
Binding(class router.Routes to self) (via modules: com.google.inject.util.Modules$OverrideModule -> play.api.inject.guice.GuiceableModuleConversions$$anon$1)
```

It seems like something wrong in controller. Where is my mistake, how to fix it?

I use:

```
JDK 1.8.0_181
SBT 0.13.5
Scala 2.12
Play Framework 2.6.20
```

**routes**:

```
GET /get_values controllers.GetValuesController.get_data_from_db(start_date_time:String, end_date_time:String, city_name:String)
```

**GetValuesController.scala**:

```
package controllers

import javax.inject._

import akka.actor.ActorSystem
import play.api.Configuration
import play.api.mvc.{AbstractController, ControllerComponents}
import play.api.libs.ws._
import scala.concurrent.duration._
import scala.concurrent.{ExecutionContext, Future, Promise}
import services._
import play.api.db.Database

class GetValuesController@Inject()(db: Database, conf: Configuration, ws: WSClient, cc: ControllerComponents, actorSystem: ActorSystem)(implicit exec: ExecutionContext) extends AbstractController(cc) {

    def get_data_from_db(start_date_time: String, end_date_time: String, city_name: String) = Action.async {
        getValue(1.second, start_date_time: String, end_date_time: String, city_name: String).map {
            message => Ok(message)
        }
    }

    private def getValue(delayTime: FiniteDuration, start_date_time: String, end_date_time: String, city_name: String): Future[String] = {
        val promise: Promise[String] = Promise[String]()

        val service: GetValuesService = new GetValuesService(db)

        actorSystem.scheduler.scheduleOnce(delayTime) {
            promise.success(service.get_values(start_date_time, end_date_time, city_name))
        }(actorSystem.dispatcher)

        promise.future
    }
}
```

**GetValuesService.scala**:

```
package services

import play.api.db.Database
import play.api.libs.json._

class GetYoutubeSpeedValuesService(db: Database) {

    def get_youtube_speed_values(start_date_time: String, end_date_time: String, city_name: String): String ={


        val SQL_STATEMENT = "SELECT " +
        "table_name.\"Stamper\" AS DATE_TIME, " +
        "table_name.\"CITY\" AS CITY, " +
        "MAX(table_name.avg) AS MAX_SPEED " +
        "FROM table_name" +
        "WHERE table_name.\"CITY\"='" +  city_name + "' " +
        "AND (table_name.\"Stamper\" BETWEEN '" + start_date_time + "' AND '" + end_date_time + "') " +
        "GROUP BY table_name.\"Stamper\", table_name.\"CITY\";"

        val connection = db.getConnection()

        var json_array = Json.arr()

        try {
            val query = connection.createStatement.executeQuery(SQL_STATEMENT)
            while (query.next()) {
                val json_object = Json.obj(
                    "DATE_TIME" -> query.getString(1),
                    "CITY" -> query.getString(2),
                    "MAX_SPEED" -> query.getString(3)
                )
                json_array +:= json_object
            }
        } finally {
            connection.close()
        }

        println(json_array)

        json_array.toString()
    }
}
```

**application.conf**:

```
db.postgres.driver=org.postgresql.Driver
db.postgres.url="jdbc:postgresql://host:port/database_name"
db.postgres.username = "username"
db.postgres.password = "password"
```

**Javascript**:

```
$.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "http://localhost:9000/get_values",
        data: {
            start_date_time: '2018-10-01 00:00:00',
            end_date_time: '2018-10-31 23:00:00',
            city_name: 'London'
        },
        success: function (result) {
            console.log(result);
        },
        error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            console.log("jqXHR: " + jqXHR);
            console.log("textStatus: " + textStatus);
            console.log("errorThrown: " + errorThrown);
        }
    });
```

**ERROR**:

```
Action Not Found
For request 'POST /get_values'
```

In the same time controller works now correctly! If I call lets say such url: `http://localhost:9000/get_values?start_date_time=2018-10-01%2000:00:00&end_date_time=2018-10-31%2023:00:00&city_name=London` it return me JSON data.

Comment: Where is the code binding the `Database` trait to an actual implementation?

Comment: @YuvalItzchakov I don't unserstant you clearly. You mean the place where I set connection to database? I set it in `application.conf` file. Check my post again please.

Comment: @YuvalItzchakov I also add all imports which I use to the code of this post.

Comment: Looking at the following answer, maybe your application.conf is wrong: https://stackoverflow.com/a/37087269/8230810

Comment: @JamesWhiteley I changed `db.postgres` to db.default. Then rebuild sbt, restart IDEA. Only after that `get_values` URL works. But I still have problem with AJAX. Can you check my post again pls.

Comment: I'm not great with AJAX but at a glance, you have defined a GET route in your `routes` file and are trying to POST to that route. It looks like you need to change your AJAX call to be a GET request with the `data` as query parameters.

Comment: @JamesWhiteley I remove this part from AJAX code `type: "POST"`. It works now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, finally we found the problem. The problem was in `application.conf` file. In my case I used next database configuration:

```
db.default.driver=org.postgresql.Driver
db.default.url="jdbc:postgresql://host:port/database_name"
db.default.username = "username"
db.default.password = "password"
```

Also in `AJAX` code I remove this part:  `type: "POST"`